# After running yarn, get fsevents command failed after Mac book update

Tags: react-native

After MacBook updated to v12.4 when I try to run yarn command on my react native project I get this error:

```
error /Users/jaugustinus/Documents/Dev/Service-Bay/node_modules/fsevents: Command failed.
Exit code: 1
Command: node install.js
Arguments: 
Directory: /Users/jaugustinus/Documents/Dev/Service-Bay/node_modules/fsevents
Output:
node:events:505
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: spawn node-gyp ENOENT
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:283:19)
    at onErrorNT (node:internal/child_process:478:16)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21)
Emitted 'error' event on ChildProcess instance at:
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:289:12)
    at onErrorNT (node:internal/child_process:478:16)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21) {
  errno: -2,
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'spawn node-gyp',
  path: 'node-gyp',
```

This command was running fine yesterday and the only change would be Mac OS update.

Tried also running

```
rm -rf node_modules
yarn cache clean
yarn
```

and still got the same error

Comment: You probably just need to clear out the cache and remove the node modules. Try this: `rm -rf node_modules && npm cache clean --force && npm install`

Comment: @Icemanind I've updated my post and have tried to remove node_modules and clear cache but still same error.

Answer (score 20):

Was getting this after upgrading my node version for a project to 20.3. Turned out the fix was to ensure node-gyp itself was up to date:

```
yarn global add node-gyp
```

Having done this, my original `yarn install` succeeded.

Answer (score 1):

The error I got was when using node version 16.15.0

If I change the node version to 17.8.0 then I am able to run yarn with no issues.